# Obtener reporte de donde se cae la QUERY exactamente - Transact SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, report

Tengo una query que me arroja un error debido a que devuelve más de 1 valor `"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."`

el tema es que necesito saber que dato exactamente se me esta duplicando, en donde se me esta cayendo.

existe alguna herramienta de SqlServer que me indique esta información?

QUERY:

```
SELECT
vij.INVOICEACCOUNT,
(
SELECT 
vt.NAME 
FROM [MSAXPRODG4].[dbo].[VENDTABLE] AS vt 
WHERE vt.ACCOUNTNUM = vij.INVOICEACCOUNT
)AS NOMBRE,
vij.INVOICEID,
vij.LEDGERVOUCHER,
CONVERT(CHAR(10), vij.DOCUMENTDATE, 103) AS FECHA,
vij.DOCUMENTDATE,
(
SELECT
CONVERT(CHAR(10), f.fecha_recepcion, 103)
FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Factura] AS f
WHERE f.rut_proveedor = REPLACE(vij.INVOICEACCOUNT, '-', '')
AND f.numero_documento = vij.INVOICEID
)AS FECHA_RECEPCION_SCD,
(
SELECT
f.fecha_recepcion
FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Factura] AS f
WHERE f.rut_proveedor = REPLACE(vij.INVOICEACCOUNT, '-', '')
AND f.numero_documento = vij.INVOICEID
)AS FECHA_RECEPCION_SCD_ORIGINAL,
SUBSTRING(vij.PAYMENT, 0, LEN(vij.PAYMENT)-0) AS PAYMENT,
CONVERT(INT, vij.INVOICEAMOUNT) AS INVOICEAMOUNT,
(
SELECT
vts.CLOSED
FROM [MSAXPRODG4].[dbo].[VENDTRANS] AS vts
WHERE vts.ACCOUNTNUM = vij.INVOICEACCOUNT
AND vts.INVOICE = vij.INVOICEID
AND vts.VOUCHER = vij.LEDGERVOUCHER
)AS FECHA_PAGO
FROM [MSAXPRODG4].[dbo].[VENDINVOICEJOUR] AS vij
WHERE vij.LEDGERVOUCHER LIKE('FA%')
AND EXISTS(
SELECT
*
FROM [MSAXPRODG4].[dbo].[VENDTRANS] AS vts
WHERE vts.ACCOUNTNUM = vij.INVOICEACCOUNT
AND vts.INVOICE = vij.INVOICEID
AND vts.VOUCHER = vij.LEDGERVOUCHER
AND vts.CLOSED = '1900-01-01' 
)
AND LEN(PAYMENT) > 0
AND PAYMENT NOT IN('TC', 'CO')
AND CONVERT(CHAR(10), vij.DOCUMENTDATE, 103) = '15/09/2017'
```

Comment: Debes aportar mas información, como por ejemplo la query que contiene la subquery.. También las tablas asociadas.

Comment: acabo de editar, adjunte la query estimado.

Comment: @FranciscoAcevedo, una forma es la siguiente: en Sql Server, copia esta consulta, colócale `TOP 1` a las sub-consultas *(una por una)* y ejecuta la consulta completa, sabrás cuál es la sub-consulta que obtiene mas de un elemento.

Comment: Me parece que podes correr cada uno de los queries individualmente y ahi ves cual te devuelve mas de un resultado

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave probe de tu forma, uno por uno, el unico que me devuelve datos es el primer subselect `(
SELECT top 1
vt.NAME 
FROM [MSAXPRODG4].[dbo].[VENDTABLE] AS vt 
WHERE vt.ACCOUNTNUM = vij.INVOICEACCOUNT
)AS NOMBRE,` si pongo el `top 1` en los demas subselect me arroja el mismo error.
pero si mantengo este top 1 en el primer subselect y aparte lo pongo en los otros subselect me devuelve los mismos datos como si lo aplicara solo al primer subselect.

Comment: @FranciscoAcevedo, entonces debes modificar esa sub-consulta. Solo te pude ayudar en esa parte para ayudarte a depurar ese error. Para que recibas mas ayuda, yo te aconsejo elaborar mejor tu pregunta, agrega la descripción de las tablas, datos de las tablas y resultados esperados. Saludos.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave gracias por tu consejo, gracias a esa instancia logré encontrar el dato que me estaba arrojando error.